# Sharding based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, sharding, distributed-system

Why is database sharding based on timestamp or monotonically increasing number not recommended?
I am referring to the anti pattern mentioned at: https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/whitepapers/optimizing-schema-design#anti-pattern_timestamp_ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that your link called it an "anti-pattern".  I have similar thoughts...

That seems like an odd way to shard.  It implies that writes will be pounding on one server for a while (a day, or whatever the shard range is).  This makes the "recent" data hard to `SELECT` from because of all the writes going on.  Meanwhile, the "old" data is sitting idle??

Usually, Sharding is based on "user_id" or "company_id".  This spreads the load--both read and write--across the shards.  After all, sharding is to spread the load.

But, sharding should not be done until you have so much activity that the traffic cannot be handled in a single machine.  Sharding is complex because of having to redirect traffic to the appropriate machine, and because of the really messy code needed if a single action needs to look in multiple shards.

If you do have a lot of traffic, I will be happy to advise further.  But I would start by seeing if the traffic can be made efficient enough to live on a single server.

Another thing to note:  There is essentially no parallelism in MySQL.

Comment: My use case is that: I need to find out recent data based on some filter. Consider an example where some files are created on a cloud service and we need to find all the files which were created after certain time 't'. Is there a problem if we use time_stamp % num_shards as the shard key?

Comment: `WHERE ts > '2021-01-01'` or `WHERE ts > NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR` and have `INDEX(ts)`.  Sharding is for massive amounts of data and a massive number of writes.  Partitioning is sort of "sharding withing one machine".  Neither of these seems useful for your use case.  How many rows inserted per second?  How many writes per second?

Comment: The writes are expected to be at 1500/sec while the reads are going to be 1000/sec.

Comment: OK, 1500 writes/sec is into sharding territory.  More questions: Type of disk (HDD/SSD)?  Are those single-row inserts or batched?  Show us the 'main' queries.

Comment: Type of disk I have not decided yet. These will.be single row inserts and the main query would look something like: WHERE ts > t. t is the last time this query ran.

Comment: Can the insets be batched?  A single insert with 100 rows is about 10 times as fast as 100 single-row `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Start the `PRIMARY KEY` with `ts`.  If you also have an auto_increment `id`, do this:  `PRIMARY KEY(ts, id), INDEX(id)`.  But... is there more to the `WHERE`?

Comment: (I'm happy to discuss sharding, but it sounds like you can achieve your goals with a single server without partitioning.  Hence, simpler.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229782/discussion-between-nishant-gupta-and-rick-james).